# how to restart colormap when it gets to the last color? Or how to make the first colors in colormap last longer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, 3d

I have this 3d plot, but after a while the only color it puts is yellow, how can I make cmap start again from the first color instead of just plotting with yellow after a while?

Or how can I make the colors equally distributed? and prevent them from going very rapidly to yellow.[image]

The colormap code line is the following

```
cm_gradient = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
```

This is how I call it

```
if numb_walkers in snapshot or finished_cluster==True:

                col=np.arange(len(seeds_z_coordinates))

                fig=plt.figure()

                snapshots_taken.append(numb_walkers)
                ax=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
                ax.scatter(seeds_z_coordinates, seeds_y_coordinates, seeds_x_coordinates,  s=1, c=col, marker='o', cmap=cm_gradient) # cmap=cmap)

                label=str(numb_walkers)
                plt.title("Crystal Growth by DLA")
                ax.set_xlim3d(0, box_dim)
                ax.set_ylim3d(0,box_dim)
                ax.set_zlim3d(0,box_dim)
                ax.set_xlabel("x")
                ax.set_ylabel("y")
                ax.set_zlabel("z")
                plt.savefig("Gifs and images/{}_walkers.png".format(label), dpi=200)
                plt.close()
```

Comment: It's not too clear what the problem is here. The values used to colorize the points are equally distributed (because they are just the first `n` positive integers. The "last color" is simply the last value in that list - when the last color is plotted, there is no more points to plot, restarting anything does not make sense. To produce less yellow, you could square the `col` array (`c = col**2`) - not sure if that makes any sense, but it'll reduce the number of yellow points in the plot.